Python - Way to interact with GUI from script executed by crontab - Raspian OS
I want to interact with the GUI of my display(Open an image every time I press a button that I have interfaced via GPIO) via a python script which is executed after bootup. (I have edited crontab file to execute a shell script which in turn executes the python file). I bascially want a setup that works without the need a mouse or keyboard.
However, the image does not open. Python logs say: "Error: no "view" rule for type "image/png" passed its test case"
Note: The program works perfectly fine when I execute the shell file manually. The problem occurs only when the script is executed via crontab
What can be the possible cause for this?
